# Different styles for facebook sharing content

Tags: facebook, facebook-share

we are currently sharing dynamic content off out website all is working as expected.

One issue we are trying to resolve not sure if it can be done is when we click share we see our content like this:

[image]

Yet when click other sites I see something like this:

[image]

My question is can I alter the way my share looks (first pic)? so it looks like the second photo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you follow the guidelines for the `og:image` tag:

> Use images that are at least 1200 x 630 pixels for the best display on high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that are 600 x 315 pixels to display link page posts with larger images.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

You should also consider reading the rest of that page.